# Llamada a variable dinamica Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Que tal. Mi duda es la siguiente:

Yo creo una variable en javascript dentro de un each:

```
window["opcion" + v.id] = {var1: 1, var2: 2};
```

Si yo quiero acceder a ella dentro del mismo each ¿Cómo debo hacer referencia a ella?

Podria ser así: `"opcion"+v.id` ó `opcion+v.id`

Espero puedan respuesta a mi duda.

Comment: La segunda opción solo podría funcionar si existiera una variable llamada `opcion` y cuyo valor sea igual a `opcion`. Es decir `var opcion = 'opcion';`. En caso contrario debería dar error ya que la variable `opcion` no esta definida.

Comment: Si `v.id`es un número, te recomiendo guardar las opciones en un array: `opciones[v.id]=...` . La respuesta de Einer te soluciona la duda, pero no creo que llenar `window` de variables sea una buena idea.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando la primera opción lo puedes lograr:

```js
var v = {id:1}
window["opcion" + v.id] = {var1: 1, var2: 2};

// accedemos al objeto utilizando acceso por indice
console.log(window["opcion"+v.id]);
console.log(window["opcion"+v.id].var1);
console.log(window["opcion"+v.id].var2);
```

Javascript es un lenguaje bien dinamico por lo que nos ayuda mucho en ciertas circunstancias.

Comment: window["option"+v.rancho_id] = {
            center: v.punto_inicial,
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapa), window["option"+v.rancho_id]);

Este es mi problema en general. 

Creo la variable con las opciones para el mapa pero al momento de mandarla en las opciones para crearlo, es que tengo la duda de como llamarla.

Comment: Necesitas alguna ayuda con eso?

Answer (score 1):

Hacemos un `each` a un select para obtener cada uno de sus hijos `option` que por cada iteracion agregamos un nuevo valor a la variable global window espero sea lo que buscas

Si lo que quieres es agregar para despues utilizar los valores puedes usar la function `push` y agregar valores por cada iteracion.

espero te ayude saludos.

```js
$("#myselect").find("option").each(function(){
  window["option"+$(this).attr("value")] = {var1: 1, var2: 2};
  //obtener el objeto completo
  console.log("objeto:",window["option"+$(this).attr("value")])
  //obtener la propiedad var1 dentro del objeto
  console.log("var1:",window["option"+$(this).attr("value")].var1)
  //obtener la propiedad var2 dentro del objeto
  console.log("var2:",window["option"+$(this).attr("value")].var2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" class="" name="">
    <option value="opcion1">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">opcion 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">opcion 3</option>
    <option value="opcion4">opcion 4</option>
  </select>
```